# asp.net core 3.1 HttpClient, Json serializes two times

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying to use an API that needs JSON for the post request.

Here you can see what I am trying to do:

```
using(var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var jsonSettings = new JsonSerializerOptions
    {
        Encoder = JavaScriptEncoder.UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping,
        WriteIndented = true
    };
    var content = new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(new MyObject(data), jsonSettings), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage
    {
        RequestUri = new Uri(URL),
        Content = content,
        Method = HttpMethod.Post
    };
    request.Headers.Accept.Add( new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
}
```

When I send the request I get this JSON:

```
{
    "email": "Tester \\u003Ctest@test.test\\u003E",
    "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. \\r\\nAenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean Massa."
}
```

As you can see I get things like \\u003C while it needs to be \u003C

I have no idea how this happens. I can only think that the content cat serialized twice. so \ becomes \ which breaks my request as the email is not following the standard.

If you need more info just ask. :)

Comment: The backslashes have been escaped I think, that's all. It's certainly not double serialising the JSON, it would look a lot worse than that if it was. Are you unable to deserialise it correctly?

Comment: Well, that JSON text that I posted is what I get. My input text would be this: Email: "Tester <test@test.test>" and Text: "text \r\n text"

Comment: Ok. But I asked, are you unable to deserialise it correctly? If you're showing me the JSON that's fine, but then it isn't deserialised. So what happens if you try and deserialise it?

Comment: So I found out that I couldn't deserialize it because I hade no parameterless constructors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out my problem. I forgot to make a parameterless constructor in my object class. This resulted in my weird JSON output.

```
public class Data
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

//  Added code
    public Data() {}

    public Data(string email, string text)
    {
        this.Email = email;
        this.Text = text;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` instead of JsonSerializer.Serialize.

I have created a class :

```
  public class Test
    {
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string text { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is code:

```
      Test data= new Test()
                 {
                      email="Tester \u003Ctest@test.test\u003E",
                       text=@"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
    Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean Massa."

                 }; 

 using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var jsonSettings = new JsonSerializerOptions
                {
                    Encoder = JavaScriptEncoder.UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping,
                    WriteIndented = true
                };
                var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                var request = new HttpRequestMessage
                {
                    RequestUri = new Uri(url),
                    Content = content,
                    Method = HttpMethod.Post
                };
                request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                var response = await client.SendAsync(request);


 }
```